# Dell Inspiron 3520, installed 12.10 Can't get wifi to work

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 3520 that came pre-installed with Windows 8.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 but wasn't able to locate/install the wireless driver and had to go back to Windows 8. I'd rather have Ubuntu but I need my wifi.

Comment: wifi doesn't need to be installed in Ubuntu, it auto-detects. When you click the connectivity icon on top-right corner of your Unity desktop (usually 3rd or 4th icon from left), it should show you the wireless status.

Comment: Usually, it will just list your wireless networks, or there will be a disabled menu saying "Wireless is disabled by Hardware switch". Is that the case on your laptop ?

Comment: actually it says wireless driver not detected, i'm only able to connect via ethernet.

Comment: @patrickio What network card do you have?  We can't help you get a driver without knowing that...

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is download the driver.
Do a google search for 'broadcom bcm43142 driver linux download deb'
Download the appropriate .deb file.
Then assuming you downloaded to ~/Downloads open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
cd ~/Downloads
dpkg -i wire*.deb
```

This will install DKMS first then the driver.
You then need to reboot.

Hope this helps.